# ASP.Net Regex Replace Pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Im new on the ASP.Net. I am working on a cart function.

My cart in session.

```
0001|1,0002|1

productid|quantity,productid|quantity,
```

How i can use Regex Replace and replace only quantity;

Example; 0001|1 --- > 0001|3 (It will 3 quantities)

Thanks and sorry little english.

Comment: Regex would be overkill in this situation. Parse the data, manipulate it and write it back. Also: Show what you have tried so far with the help of a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm using Ajax, and this is a minimal corporate website. If i can replace quantity with Regex, everything will be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what you need, but if the quantity is between the two `|` you can use this code :

```
(?<=\|)(.*?)(?=\|)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rkpp.jpg

If quantity is between the `|` and the `,` use this:

```
(?<=\|)(.*?)(?=\,)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/40ogA.jpg